# SparkFiles.get() is not able to fetch file uploaded using --files option of spark-submit

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Spark-submit --files option says that the files can be accessed using SparkFiles.get('files.txt')

[image: Spark Document]

So I wrote a simple program

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkFiles
spark = SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()

print("testfile path : "+SparkFiles.get('testfile.txt'))

df=spark.read.text(SparkFiles.get('testfile.txt'))

df.show()
```

And then run using the below command :

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client --files testfile.txt testsubmit.py
```

From the logs I can see thaat the "testfile.txt" has been copied to ***hdfs://dummyIP.com:8020/user/root/.sparkStaging/application_1581404080152_0079/testfile.txt***

```
20/03/05 04:41:08 INFO Client: Source and destination file systems are the same. Not copying hdfs://dummyIP.com:8020/hdp/apps/2.6.5.0-292/spark2/spark2-hdp-yarn-archive.tar.gz
20/03/05 04:41:08 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/root/sumit/test/testfile.txt -> hdfs://dummyIP.com:8020/user/root/.sparkStaging/application_1581404080152_0079/testfile.txt
20/03/05 04:41:09 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip -> hdfs://dummyIP.com:8020/user/root/.sparkStaging/application_1581404080152_0079/pyspark.zip
```

**But SparkFiles.get('testfile.txt') is trying to fetch 'testfile.txt' from hdfs://dummyIP.com:8020/tmp/spark-f7fedc0b-c3c7-4f6e-b72c-fc0618a03deb/userFiles-c90e2d49-c153-4945-bbe2-b006221002f9/testfile.txt**

```
testfile path : /tmp/spark-f7fedc0b-c3c7-4f6e-b72c-fc0618a03deb/userFiles-c90e2d49-c153-4945-bbe2-b006221002f9/testfile.txt

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/sumit/test/testsubmit.py", line 7, in <module>
    df=spark.read.text(SparkFiles.get('testfile.txt'))
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 328, in text
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1160, in __call__
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 69, in deco
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u'Path does not exist: hdfs://dummyIP.com:8020/tmp/spark-f7fedc0b-c3c7-4f6e-b72c-fc0618a03deb/userFiles-c90e2d49-c153-4945-bbe2-b006221002f9/testfile.txt;'
```

Also note that text() function will be executed on executor nodes as is mentioned the Spark Documentations. So it seems like ***SparkFiles.get('files.txt')*** is not reading from the same location where the ***--files*** is uploading it.

Comment: I am having the same issue, looks like regression in spark